# conditional check for command line arguments in c++

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

How can me check for a condition using command line arguments in C++, for example I got a code like this

```
    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 

     if (strcmp(argv[1] , 'a')==0)
     {
         cout<<"something"<<endl;
     }
 }
```

with the arguments hello, hi etc., when my argv[1] == "hello", I want to execute some statements. 
This comparison is throwing an error char is incompatible with const char*
Is there a better way to compare these arguments?

Comment: First, you should have written "a", not 'a'. You are obviously a beginner and I advise you to look for a tutorial on pointer.
Second, there is a library called getopt for this kind of use.

Comment: `strcmp(argv[1], "a")` - notice the double quotes, which identifies the string as a pointer to an array {'a', '\0'} rather than a single character 'a'.

strcmp is meant to be used on strings, not characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'a' is an int (more accurately 1 byte integer)

"a" is a string

Replace 'a' with "a"